# dafny How to check member-value in another class

Tags: dafny

I'm trying to learn dafny and came across a problem I don't understand. 
I need to check if a user exist in an array, and I want to use a predicate for this.
I have an array of Users and every user has an id. So I want to check the id which belongs to the class User.

I get this error `Test.dfy(57,24): Error: member id does not exist in array type array`

Everything else works fine(I think).

So how do I read/access a member of another class in a predicate when I have an array of objects(User)?

Thank you for your help.
`

```
class Test {

    var users : array<User>;
    var size : int;
    var index : int;

    method Init(c : int)
    modifies this;   
    requires c > 0;
    ensures fresh(users);   
    ensures size == c; 
    ensures Check();
    ensures Empty();

{
    users := new User[c];   
    size := c;    
    index := -1;        
}

predicate Empty()
reads this`index;
{
    index == -1
}

predicate Full()
reads this`index, this`size;
{
    index == (size - 1)
}

predicate Check()
reads this;
{
    users != null && 
    size > 0 && 
    size == users.Length && 
    index >= -1 && 
    index < size 
}

method AddUser(u : User)
modifies this.users, this`index;
requires Check();
requires !Full();

ensures Check();
ensures index == old(index) + 1;
ensures users[index] == u;
{
    index := index + 1;   
    users[index] := u; 
}

predicate FindUserById(n : int)
reads this.users, this.users`id;
requires Check();
{
    exists i :: 0 <= i < users.Length ==> users[i].id == n
}

method Main()
{
    var t := new Test;
    t.Init(3);
    var u1 := new User.Init(1,23);
    var u2 := new User.Init(2,24);
    var u3 := new User.Init(3,25);
    t.AddUser(u1);
    t.AddUser(u2);
    t.AddUser(u3);
}
}

class User {

   var id : int;
   var phone : int;

   method Init(i : int, p : int)
   modifies this`id, this`phone;
   requires 0 < i < 99999;
   requires 0 < p < 99999;
   ensures id == i;
   ensures phone == p;
   {
        id := i;
        phone := p;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the part of the `reads` clause `` this.users`id ``, since `users` is an array, and arrays do not have an `id` field.

You don't need this part of the `reads` clause at all; just delete it. You'll then have to fix a few other issues before the program will verify.

Comment: Thanks but if I remove `this.users\`id` I get this error `Error: insufficient reads clause to invoke function` on the line where `Check()` is. And if I remove `Check()` I get `Error: insufficient reads clause to read field`. If I remove the whole predicate the code compiles without any errors. Could you give me a hint on how to solve this?

Comment: @rolf-ralf yes, you will still need to fix the `reads` clause to include the whole array. how about something like this? `reads this, this.users, set i | 0 <= i < users.Length :: users[i];`